# Service worker don't work anymore

Tags: javascript, service-worker

I have integrated service worker in my website. Everything used to works perfectly, but now, I have an error when my service worker try to install :

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Request failed at anonymous  service-worker.js:1

And my service worker is in the 'redundant' state.

I don't know why... I did not change my code, this is my index.html :

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  navigator.serviceWorker.register('/service-worker.js').then(function(reg) {

  if(reg.installing) {
    console.log('Service worker installing');
  } else if(reg.waiting) {
    console.log('Service worker installed');
  } else if(reg.active) {
    console.log('Service worker active');
  }

  }).catch(function(error) {
    // registration failed
console.log('Registration failed with ' + error);
  });
}
```

And here is my service-worker.js :

```
self.addEventListener('install', function(event) {
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.open('v1').then(function(cache) {
      return cache.addAll([
        '/',
        '/theme/website_mobile/js',
        '/theme/website_mobile/css',
        '/theme/website_mobile/js.js',
        '/theme/website_mobile/css.css',
        '/js/614cd8e.js',
        '/css/f1407bb.css',
        '/js/93779bc.js',
        '/js/d228ec7.js',
        '/theme/website_mobile/img/slider-home/slider1.jpg',
        '/theme/website_mobile/img/slider-home/slider2.jpg',
        '/theme/website_mobile/img/slider-home/slider3.jpg',
        '/theme/website_mobile/img/slider-home/slider4.jpg',
        '/theme/website_mobile/img/logo-website.png',
        '/theme/website_mobile/img/picto-menu-close.png',
        '/theme/website_mobile/img/picto-close.png',
        '/var/website/storage/images/media/website-medias/website-materials/5163440-1-eng-GB/website-materials_article_list_main_website_enm.jpg',
        '/theme/website_mobile/fonts/website-montserrat/Montserrat-Light.woff2',
        '/theme/website_mobile/fonts/website-montserrat/Montserrat-Regular.woff2',
        '/theme/website_mobile/fonts/website-montserrat/Montserrat-ExtraBold.woff2',
        '/theme/website_mobile/fonts/website-avenir/Fonts/065a6b14-b2cc-446e-9428-271c570df0d9.woff2',
      ]);
    })
  );
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
  event.respondWith(caches.match(event.request).then(function(response) {
    // caches.match() always resolves
    // but in case of success response will have value
    if (response !== undefined) {
      return response;
    } else {
      return fetch(event.request).then(function (response) {
        // response may be used only once
        // we need to save clone to put one copy in cache
        // and serve second one
        let responseClone = response.clone();

        caches.open('v1').then(function (cache) {
          cache.put(event.request, responseClone);
        });
        return response;
      }).catch(function (e) {
        return caches.match('/');
      });
    }
  }));
});
```

A more stranger thing is when I tried to edit my service-worker.js, I added this :

```
self.addEventListener('install', function(event) {
  **reg.update();**
```

which is a mistake, but I figured out that this works good ! I have an reg is undefined error in the console, but my service worker works good.

I tried to change the reg.update() part and put a simple console.log but, when I did that, the service-worker return in the redundant state and don't install...

I don't understand why when if I add an undefined object in the service worker code, it throw an error but it works great, and when I came back to my old code (which used to work before), it didn't install.

Maybe, I am doing it wrong somewhere... ?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try leaving your code exactly as you had it but updated the cache name (say, from `v1` to `v2`)?

Comment: Hi Andy. No. I didn't change this code at all. Even the cache names. But I have a question about this : If I change the file, the service worker would not works anymore ?

Comment: Sorry, I made a typo earlier. I meant to say, can you try changing the cache name and see what happens?

Comment: I tried. But same problem: service worker redundant... same error.

Comment: I'm wondering if, somehow, the (last) trailing comma in your assets array is screwing the promise up somehow. Maybe it's trying to fetch a null asset?

Comment: I removed it, but same problem... The only way to make it work is to add an error in the file...

Comment: Does the same behavior occur in a private tab? I'm starting to think it's a caching issue.

Comment: You could try to switch to a new profile and see if you get an error, then please tell us what line is that error and what is the exact error. Make sure you have the devtools open when you open the page for the first time because when you reload it'll come from cache. Does the error go away if you remove loading the service worker code and with a new profile?

Comment: Andy > When I test, I always use private tab and on an other navigator. Same behavior...

HMR > The error is 

`Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Request failed at anonymous service-worker.js:1`

at the first line :

`self.addEventListener('install', function(event) {`

Yep, there is no error when I remove the loading code. And I make sur that there is no cache when I test

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just ran into this after pulling my hair out for several days.

In my case one of the URLs of the list was returning a 404, which made the entire `Cache.addAll` return promise reject with the extremely unspecific error `TypeError: Request failed` ("failed on what, why?!").

If your business logic allows for graceful caching, despite any one of the urls failing, you might want to change your approach to `Cache.add` of every item of the list:

```js
var urls = ['/', ...]
self.addEventListener('install', function(event) {
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.open('v1').then(function(cache) {
      urls.forEach(function (url) {
        cache.add(url).catch(/* optional error handling/logging */);
      });
    })
  );
});
```

Comment: this line is magic : `cache.add(url).catch(/* optional error handling/logging */);`